# CSS: Como manter <li> numa mesma página sem pular pra próxima

Tags: css3

[image: for][image: Verso certificado]

Boa tarde pessoal !

Gostaria de saber como posso colocar os itens de uma lista na mesma página sem que ele vá pra página seguinte. Ex: Quero colocar o item 3 e sua descrição no lado direito da página acima, onde estão os outros itens. Já tentei colocar float em tudo, mas não consegui ajeitar. Se alguém souber de alguma ideia, algo que eu possa fazer pra consertar isso, me ajudaria muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possível alternativa seria colocar a tag `ul` com layout de duas ou mais colunas, ai economizaria espaço para caber tudo na mesma página.

```css
ul{
    columns: 2;
   -webkit-columns: 2;
   list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="itens">
  <li>Item 1 </li>
  <li>Item 2 </li>
  <li>Item 3 </li>
  <li>Item 4 </li>
  <li>Item 5 </li>
  <li>Item 6 </li>
</ul>
```